# Angular Filter console error messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

This Select box was doing what it was supposed to do but for some reason its not working anymore. 
The select box is displaying Employees that are project managers. When I select one it updates the input box with it.

Filter

```
app.filter('filterEmployees', function() {
 return function (input) {
console.log('input: ', input);
var output = [];
if (!input instanceof Array) {
  console.log('error');
  return output;
  }
  // for all TESPM's
   input.forEach(function (tespm) {
  var employees = tespm.Employees; 
  if (!employees instanceof Array) {
    console.log('error');
    return output;
  }
  // for all employees
  employees.forEach(function (employee) {
    // filter
    if (employee.EmployeeIsPM) {
      output.push(employee.EmployeeFirstName + ' ' + employee.EmployeeLastName);
    }
  });
});
console.log('output: ', output);
return output;
   };
});
```

View

```
<div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon">J. TESPM</span>
   <input style="width:150px" ng-model="TESPM" class="form-control" type="text">
   <span class="input-group-addon">J. TESPM</span>
    <select class="form-control" ng-options="empl for empl in jobArray|filterEmployees" ng-model="TESPM">
          <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```

Error in the Console

```
  {TypeError: undefined is not a function
   at g.<anonymous> (http://localhost:44301/MyScripts/app.js:215:15)
   at e (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:155:305)
   at Ia.| (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:143:226)
   at u.constant (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:154:182)
   at h [as $render] (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:190:25)
   at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:172:335)
   at g.$digest (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:98:177)
   at g.$apply (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:101:12)
   at http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:17:415
   at Object.d [as invoke] (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:30:328)
 {input:  
  [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object,     Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
output:  [] 
  input:  Object {}
```

Line 215 in the filter is

```
// for all TESPM's
input.forEach(function (tespm) {
```